# Donation system loop where the system will ask again until the fixed target amount is reached

Tags: python

I wrote this code but I don't know how to add all donations for each donor when the loop runs several times.
It should print like this:

```
Donor 1 has donated £10 in total
Donor 2 has donated £15 in total...
```

```
import random
number_of_staff = (random.randint(3,5))
suggested_donation = (random.randint(10, 20))
amount_to_be_raised = number_of_staff * suggested_donation
a = []

def amount():
    print('Amount to be raised by team number ______is £', amount_to_be_raised, '.')
    print('Number of staff that will contribute is', number_of_staff)
    print('Suggested donation is', suggested_donation)

def donation_loop(number_of_staff):
    for j in range(number_of_staff):
        print('Donor', j + 1)
        actual_donation = int(input('Please enter donation £'))
        a.append(actual_donation)
        global b
        b = sum(a)
        print('The total sum donated is', b)

def stop():
    while b < amount_to_be_raised:
        donation_loop(number_of_staff)
    else:
        pass

amount()
donation_loop(number_of_staff)
stop()
```

Comment: You could create a dictionary which contains a list of donations for each donor.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, you have several ways to fix it, my favorite one is as follows:

```
import random
number_of_staff = (random.randint(3,5))
suggested_donation = (random.randint(10, 20))
amount_to_be_raised = number_of_staff * suggested_donation
a = {}

def amount():
    print('Amount to be raised by team number ______is £', amount_to_be_raised, '.')
    print('Number of staff that will contribute is', number_of_staff)
    print('Suggested donation is', suggested_donation)

def donation_loop(number_of_staff):
    global total_donations
    for j in range(number_of_staff):
        print('Donor', j + 1)
        actual_donation = int(input('Please enter donation £'))
        total_donations += actual_donation
        if f'Donor{j + 1}' not in a:
          a[f'Donor{j + 1}'] = []
        a[f'Donor{j + 1}'].append(actual_donation)
        print('The total sum donated is', total_donations)

def stop():
    while total_donations < amount_to_be_raised:
        donation_loop(number_of_staff)

amount()
total_donations = 0
stop()
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you very much.